# Swift OpenGL type conversion

Tags: swift, opengl-es

When creating an OpenGL-es application in swift, you have to convert all the parameters to their gl equivalenets. For example...

```
func createCamera(screenWidth:Int, screenHeight:Int){
    glViewport(GLint(0), GLint(0), GLsizei(screenWidth), GLsizei(screenHeight));

}
```

As you can see I have to convert every glViewPort() parameter to the data type that OpenGL likes, such as **Glint**. Is there a more efficient way of doing this? I feel like with swift all I've been doing is wrapping everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way it is. (For now, at least? As always, [file a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com) if you'd like to see Apple change things.) Neither Swift nor OpenGL are really designed around being friendly to each other — OpenGL is a C API, and Swift's API bridging seems to be more centered around ObjC APIs and their conventions.

You could probably make a few type extensions and function overloads to make working with GL from Swift a bit smoother. For example, if you implement `extension GLint : IntegerLiteralConvertible` sensibly, you'll be able to pass integer literals to GL APIs without wrapping each in a `GLint()` conversion. Making GL functions take Swift types would be a taller order, but only due to the sheer number of them, not their complexity. For example:

```
func glViewport(x: Int, y: Int, width: Int, height: Int) {
    GL.glViewport(GLint(x), GLint(y), GLsizei(width), GLsizei(height)
}
```

I wouldn't be surprised if someone were already doing something like this and publishing a library, but I haven't heard of any such efforts yet.

Comment: Ok thanks. I guess in the grand scheme of things it isn't so bad.